# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException caused by Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, response, webmethod

In my application I am calling a WebMethod from JavaScript, where I am trying to redirect to some page:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Logout() {            
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {                            
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Logout.aspx");               
    }
    return "";
}
```

The aspx page:

```
    <input onclick="callLogout();" id="btn" type="button" value="Click Me" />

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebServices/EMSWebService.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        function callLogout() {
            EMSApplication.Web.WebServices.EMSWebService.Logout(OnComplete, OnError);
        }

        function OnComplete(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

        function OnError(result) {
            alert(result.get_message());
        }
    </script>
```

And I am getting:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

in my VS2010's Output window.

Why I am getting this exception and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't just catch the exception. Use the overload of Redirect which takes a boolean. Pass false to indicate that you don't want the thread aborted.

Comment: I'll help you to help yourself: Here is the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx

Comment: please don't use this approach.... wrong answer because you will still get thread abort and... your code after the redirect still runs!!!

Comment: @Yuki not sure what you are talking about. You can specify that you don't want a thread abort. That's the point of this answer. You of course need to ensure that you end processing yourself now that you don't abort the thread.

Answer (score 11):

### The ideal way to redirect is to call `Response.Redirect(someUrl, false)` and then call [`CompleteRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest)

Passing false to `Response.Redirect(...)` will prevent the `ThreadAbortException` from being raised, however it is still important to end the page lifecycle by calling [`CompleteRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest).

> When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for
>   one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to
>   false and **then call the CompleteRequest() method**. If you specify true
>   for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the End method for
>   the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception
>   when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web
>   application performance, which is why **passing false for the
>   endResponse parameter is recommended**. For more information, see the
>   End method.

Note that when the `Response.Redirect(...)` method is called, a new thread is spawned with a brand new page lifecycle to handle the new redirected response.  When the new response finishes, it calls `Response.End()` on the original response which eventually throws a `ThreadAbortException` and raises the `EndRequest` event.  If you prevent `Response.End()` from being called (by passing false to `Response.Redirect`) then you need to call [`CompleteRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest) which:

> Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline
>   chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.

### Word of Caution:

If you call `Response.Redirect(someUrl, false)` allowing code continue to execute, you may want to change your code such that the processing gracefully stops.  Sometimes this is as easy as adding a `return` to a void method call.  However, if you are in a deep call stack, this is much trickier and if you don't want more code executing it might be easier to pass true like `Response.Redirect(someUrl, true)` and purposely expect the `ThreadAbortException` - which by the way isn't a bad thing, you should expect it during `Response.Redirect(...)` and `Server.Transfer(...)` calls.

### ThreadAbortException Cannot Be Stopped By Catching the Exception

The ThreadAbortException is not your ordinary exception.  Even if you wrap your code in a try catch block, the ThreadAbortException will immediately be raised after the finally clause.

> When a call is made to the Abort method to destroy a thread, the
>   common language runtime throws a ThreadAbortException.
>   **ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it
>   will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block**. When
>   this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the finally blocks
>   before ending the thread. Because the thread can do an unbounded
>   computation in the finally blocks or **call Thread.ResetAbort to cancel
>   the abort**, there is no guarantee that the thread will ever end. If you
>   want to wait until the aborted thread has ended, you can call the
>   Thread.Join method. Join is a blocking call that does not return until
>   the thread actually stops executing.

Often what I've seen in code is a try catch block around Response.Redirect that will log exceptions that are not ThreadAbortExceptions (since you expect those).  Example:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
   try
   {
      // Do some logic stuff
      ...

      if (someCondition)
      {
         Response.Redirect("ThatOneUrl.aspx", true);
      }
   }
   catch (ThreadAbortException)
   {
      // Do nothing.  
      // No need to log exception when we expect ThreadAbortException
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // Looks like something blew up, so we want to record it.
      someLogger.Log(ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Thanks for including the Word of Caution which points out (as is usual in this game) that there's not always one "right" way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard exception caused by `Response.Redirect` caught only if you have an explicit `try-catch` over a block which does the redirect. ASP.NET throws it upon redirection so that no code is executed after you redirect.

A solution is to add an empty catch to swallow this particular exception

```
try {
   ...
   Response.Redirect( ... );
}
catch ( ThreadAbortException ) { } // swallow the exception
catch ( Exception ex ) { 
   // an existing catch clause
}
```

Comment: Note the ThreadAbortException can also happen if you do a `Response.End` within a `try-catch` block.